# C# and Javascript: Share algorithm

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, algorithm

I am going to write an ASP.net web application using C#. My webapp is highly interactive.

Now I have the situation that I need to do some more complex calculation of some values. The thing is, that the user should be able to view the result of those calculations in real time while he drags some objects on the website. Every time he passes a pixel the algorithm does some calculation.
That would be no problem at all. Just write some Algorithms in JavaScript. The problem is: When the user drops the previously dragged element, the browser must do an Ajax request to the server and validate the calculated inputs. Basically that means the server has to run the exact same algorithm(s). But of course I want to write them only once. So I don’t want to create a C# class and a JavaScript function and maintain both.

Do you have any ideas how I could achieve this? Can I write the algorithms in JavaScript and call it on the server with C# or the other way around? Write that in C# and compile to JS and download the JS from the browser?

Any info on this would be awesome!
Thank you very much!

Ps.: i do not have lot of experience with C# because i am more of a Java and web Developer.

Comment: *Can I write the algorithms in JavaScript and call it on the server*. Yes you can and already are (*browser must do an Ajax request*). So you can make an ajax request to the server to do the work for you.

Comment: You could do computation server side only, using websockets (signalR) or Ajax to send the data back and forth. You could throw ina debounce function to avoid too many calls

Comment: FYI You cannot compile C# into Javascript. They are **very** different languages.

Comment: You can technically use C# code in Javascript using `Edge.js` http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind extra latency and some hazards, you can do computing on web pages.

When project loads into memory, it also (from command line) opens a browser with url of "serve" page.

Whenever a request is sent to server by a client, server queues that on some producer-consumer context.

Serve page gets request (by web service, once per several seconds to check), computes and sends result to server then server does rest of it.

But browsers can **crash** or different platforms may **not be compatible** %100. Also sending repetative webservice requests are **bad for performance**. If multiple requests are to be processed, there need to exist multiple active browser windows/tabs which is also bad for performance. But if you have full control of server, you can try and benchmark it.

```
 (javascript)
 client ------> 
 client ------>       server   -----> store result in db
                       |  ^
                       |  |
                       v  |
                 (C#web_service)  (consume)
                    work queue  ----------> server page (javascript)
                                <--------- 
                      ^  |       (check if queue>0)
                      |  |
                      |  |
                      |  v
                   server page (javascript)
```

Also this would make cpu consume unnecessary electricity energy. You should use better communication mechanisms like socket server for messaging to server page to signal work start and getting result back with web service or same method clients use. This can decrease energy consumption.

Having multiple browsers and different versions of them running in virtual machines could help compatibility.